# Is it Possible for Windows 8.1 Pro N to join a Samba Domain?

Tags: windows-8.1, samba, domain

The OS Windows 8.1 Pro N is not on the list of supported OS's https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Joining_a_Windows_Client_or_Server_to_a_Domain

Have anyone tried this before all i get is this error "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

Comment: Are you talking about a Samba 4.x Active Directory domain, or Samba 3.x "NT4" domain? Support for the latter is slowly being removed from Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8.1 Pro is on the list.

The only difference between the Pro and Pro N versions of windows (windows 10 included), is that the N versions do not natively have the Windows Media Feature Pack installed. As a result, things like xbox gaming center don't work, but anything like domain features will work normally.

A message about the specific domain could not be contacted usually refers to DNS server not being configured properly.

Make sure that the DHCP server gives the IP address of a DNS server in your network, and that this DNS server has an IP address mapping to your Samba domain, so that when you request to join the domain, and provide the domain name, the pc already knows what the IP address is.

Do note, if your domain is configured as follows:

```
Domainname: Domain
Domain FQDN: domain.local
```

It may not work if you specify Domain as domain name, but only domain.local.